# curl complex usage with pattern

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to get 2 files using curl based on some pattern but that doesn't seem to work:

Files:
 
SystemOut_15.04.01_21.12.36.log
 
SystemOut_15.04.01_15.54.05.log

```
curl -f -k -u "login:password" https://myserver/cgi-bin/logviewer/index.cgi?getlogfile=SystemOut_15.04.01_21.12.36.log'&'server=qwerty123.com'&'numlines=100000000'&'appenv=MBL%20-%20PROD'&'directory=/app/WAS/was85/profiles/node/logs/mbl-server1
```

I know there is -A key but it doesn't work since my file is inside the link.
 
How can I extract those 2 files using a pattern?

Comment: The file to fetch is the `getLogFile` query parameter? Can you send that parameter twice? If not I think you just get to call curl twice.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot send the parameter twice. This is just the example of 2 logs, in fact I have lots of them so I need to have some universal solution to get them all.

Comment: If your URL can only take one log file name at a time then you can't get them all at once with it. If there isn't some other query you can run to get them all somehow then you get to loop over the names and run `curl` multiple times yourself.

Comment: I can get the contents of directory which log files, not sure whether this can help?
curl -f -k -u "login:password" https://myserver/cgi-bin/logviewer/index.cgi??listdirectory=/app/WAS/was85/profiles/node/logs/mbl-server1'&'&appenv=MBL%20-%20PROD&server=qwerty123.com

Comment: If you can get the log files from that then yes it can. What format is the list in?

Comment: The format is as follows:-rw-r----- 1 was85usr wasgroup 1912331 Apr 1 22:59 SystemOut_15.04.01_23.00.00.log
-rw-r----- 1 was85usr wasgroup 3145473 Apr 2 08:16 SystemOut_15.04.02_08.16.46.log
-rw-r----- 1 was85usr wasgroup 3145631 Apr 2 11:26 SystemOut_15.04.02_11.26.56.log
-rw-r----- 1 was85usr wasgroup 3145717 Apr 2 14:12 SystemOut_15.04.02_14.12.02.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did that myself. One curl gets the list of logs on the webpage. Another downloads those files.

The code looks like:

```
for file in $(curl -f -k -u "user:pwd" https://selfservice.pwj.com/cgi-bin/logviewer/index.cgi?listdirectory=/app/smx_client_mob/data/log'&'appenv=MBL%20-%20PROD'&'server=xshembl04pap.she.pwj.com | grep href | sed 's/.*href="//' | sed 's/".*//' | sed 's/javascript:getLog//g' | sed "s/['();]//g" | grep -i 'service' | grep '^[a-zA-Z].*'); do
curl -o $file -f -k -u "user:pwd" https://selfservice.pwj.com/cgi-bin/logviewer/index.cgi?getlogfile="$file"'&'server=xshembl04pap.she.pwj.com'&'numlines=100000000'&'appenv=MBL%20-%20PROD'&'directory=/app/smx_client_mob/data/log; done
```

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and quote your variable usage but other than that this looks at least serviceable (that `grep`/`sed` chain is ugly and can almost certainly be cleaned up too. Also you can just single quote the *entire* non `"$file"` bits of the URL instead of needing to just quote the ampersands.